# Using Ajax to call PHP that updates data in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been researching this for awhile and there are a lot of similar questions that have been asked. I tried researching as much as I could and came up with a code that *should* work in theory... but for whatever reason, it just doesn't. I can't seem to figure it out!

I am using JQuery/AJax to call a php file and update SQL records. Here is the general gist of the code. Whats left out is essentially a button click action which calls the ajax function. The Php is going to (eventually) add the StoreID value to an array, serialize it and add it into mysql.

Each piece of the code works on their own, but when put together it just doesn't work!

Java Script Code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'storeid.php',
           data: {StoreID: IDjs[x] },
           success: function(reponse) { 
                $('#error').html('Success! SkipID: ' + IDjs[x]);                     
                onStateNext(); },
           error : function(code, message){
                $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + JSON.stringify(code) + ', Error Message: ' + JSON.stringify(message));}
           });
```

The weird thing about this code, is that the "Success" functions get output. The success callback is displayed and the proceeding script is run.. despite the fact that it doesn't appear to actually send the StoreID variable to the php file.

The PHP Code (storeid.php):

```
$test=$_POST['StoreID'];
if (isset($test)) 
{
    global $conn2;
    $memberid = $_SESSION['memberID'];
    $testarray = array(7,8,$test);
    $serialized_data = serialize($testarray);                             
    $insertsql = "UPDATE StoreIDs SET IDs = '$serialized_data' WHERE MemberID = $memberid";
     if (mysqli_query($conn2, $insertsql)) 
     {
         echo "Updated with StoreID: " . $test;
      } else {
          echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn2);
      } 
} else {echo "no isset value"; }
```

This code also works when run without the ajax. It'll properly update the record when called directly by php but not when called by the ajax script above.

Any ideas of what I could have done wrong?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: that helped a bit @JayBlanchard, I didn't realized I could see request/responses in Firefox before. Looks liked it's responding with "Error Updating Record" which is actually a good thing..... probably means its not getting the sql credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out thanks to @JayBlanchard. You can use the firefox developer tools to see server responses, which allowed to see the error messages and realize that it was communicating but simply not getting the credentials from the database.

Turns out you can't use global variables if the database file isn't included. I thought it didn't need it, since it works fine when running server side, but since ajax is run client side after the server has closed the connections for the database, it needs to be opened again!